# How to replace reactive with reactiveVal and ObserveEvent in R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

In studying R Shiny I see that you can use `reactive()` without an `observeEvent()` as shown in the demo code below. However I am trying to learn the use of the combined `reactiveVal()` and `observeEvent()` functions.

In the demo code, the user can opt to show only the first 4 rows of the data frame (called "data") via the radio button. Super simple. It works fine as written using only `reactive()` without `observeEvent()` in the server section. But I am trying to replace this with a combination of `reactiveVal()` and `observeEvent()` as shown in the commented-out (#) section in the demo code. What am I doing wrong? How can I make `reactiveVal()` and `observeEvent()` work together to give the same results?

Demo code:

```
library(shiny)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9)
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h4(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "showData",
               label = "Show from original dataframe:",
               choiceNames = c('All','First 4 rows'),
               choiceValues = c('All','Rows'),
               selected = 'All',
               inline = TRUE
              ),
  h4(strong("Reactive results:")), 
  tableOutput("choices"),
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  # Choices <- reactiveVal()
  # 
  # observeEvent(
  #   input$showData, {
  #     if(input$showData == 'Rows'){Choices <- data[1:4,]} else {Choices <- data}
  #   }
  # )
  
  Choices <- reactive(if(input$showData == 'Rows'){data[1:4,]} else {data})
  
  output[["choices"]] <- renderTable({Choices()}
  )

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Define a `choices` element in your `reactiveValues`: `rv <- reactiveValues(choices=c())`.  Populate the choices inside an observable:`rv$choices <- data[1:4,]`.  Refer to `rv$choices`  (note the absence of brackets (`()`) wherever you have refered to your `Choices()` reactive.

Comment: Hello, is this what you mean? I can't get it to work:  rv <- reactiveValues(choices=c())
  observeEvent(input$showData, {if(input$showData == 'Rows'){rv$choices <- data[1:4,]} else {data}})
  output[["choices"]] <- renderTable({choices()})

Comment: Not quite.  As I wrote in my first comment, `output[["choices"]] <- renderTable({ rv$choices })`, not `renderTable({ choices() })`.

Comment: Since I am new to this, please advise. Is it better, or more useful for the community, for me to post an answer with the working code (having followed Limey's advice) or to instead edit the original question with the working code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the resolved corrected code, incorporating Limey's comments:

```
library(shiny)

data <- 
  data.frame(
    ID = c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3),
    Period = c(1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3),
    Values = c(5, 10, 15, 0, 2, 4, 3, 6, 9)
  )

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  h4(strong("Base data frame:")), 
  tableOutput("data"),
  radioButtons(inputId = "showData",
               label = "Show from original dataframe:",
               choiceNames = c('All','First 4 rows'),
               choiceValues = c('All','Rows'),
               selected = 'All',
               inline = TRUE
              ),
  h4(strong("Reactive results:")), 
  tableOutput("choices"),
  )

server <- function(input, output, session) {
 
  output$data <- renderTable(data)
  
  # The below uses combo of reactiveValues() and observeEvent(), per Limey's comments:
  rv <- reactiveValues(choices=c()) # reactiveValues is for multiple reactive values, and reactiveVal is for a single reactive value
  observeEvent(input$showData, {
      if(input$showData == 'Rows'){rv$choices <- data[1:4,]} 
      else {rv$choices <- data}
      }
    )
  output[["choices"]] <- renderTable({ rv$choices })

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```